# Цикл со стремлением идёт не в ту сторону

Tags: обсуждение, 1-апреля

Написал цикл, в котором переменная `q` от `4` стремится к `-8`. Но когда запускаю этот код, то вместо вывода `4 3 2 ... -7` получаю `4 5 6 7`. Почему цикл идёт не в ту сторону, да ещё и игнорирует минус у восьмёрки?

```js
for     // запускаем цикл
(       
var     // по переменной
q       // q 
=       // с начальным значением
4       // 4
;       // так чтобы
q       // она
-->     // стремилась к
-8      // -8
;       // и после каждого выполнения тела
++      // переходим к следующему шагу
q       // по переменной q
)
console // консоль
.       // просим
log     // отобразить
(
q       // текущее значение переменной q
)
```

Comment: @pavel, пробовал `--` для перехода к предыдущему шагу вместо `++` для перехода к следующему, но браузер настолько пугается, что аж виснет :)

Comment: Надо это было задавать с нового пользователя)

Comment: Стремглав бежит.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Браузер сильно боится минусов, особенно если их 2 и они в начале строки. Поэтому просто уберем их. Но просто так нельзя, надо вернуть куда-нибудь ниже. Я отредактировал ваш код, теперь он работает.

```js
for     // запускаем цикл
(       
var     // по переменной
q       // q 
=       // с начальным значением
4       // 4
;       // так чтобы
q       // она
       // убрали, не будем пугать
+8      // плюсов он не боится
;       // и после каждого выполнения тела
      // переходим к следующему шагу
q--      // надо же вернуть что убрали
)
console // консоль
.       // просим
log     // отобразить
(
q       // текущее значение переменной q
)
```

Answer (score 8):

На самом деле, в глубине души, переменная стремится именно туда, куда вы (как родитель) её направили. Но обстоятельства часто накладывают свои ограничения на устремления переменных и они могут сбиться с пути из-за минусов в жизненном цикле.

Попробуйте так:

```js
for (var q = 4; q > -8; q--) {
  console.log(q);
}
```

Таким образом вы покажете ей куда лучшую жизненную цель (`-8`) и будете сами минусовать её помехи на пути (`q--`).

Answer (score 0):

Несколько полезных ссылок по теме, возможно помогут автору лучше разобраться:

[Инкремент/декремент - JavaScript.ru](https://learn.javascript.ru/operators#%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82)

[Как работает инкремент и декремент в JavaScript](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TLYDpW6bKDQ)

Comment: В метках "1-апреля", вопрос подозрительно похож на сарказм, в ответах очень серьёзно обсуждают бред... Хотя нет, эти подозрения - чушь, @Qwertiy - бездарь!

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/154787)

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/154787)